# Gatling throttle is not reaching the configured requests per second

Tags: performance, performance-testing, gatling, throttling, scala-gatling

I don't know if it's a bug or I don't know the real behaviour of [Gatling Throttling](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup#throttling) `throttle` operation but I don't know how to reproduce a scenario.

I want to have a constant amount of 15 requests per second in 10 minutes.

My setup is as follows:

```
setUp(scn.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(45) during(10 minutes)).protocols(httpProtocol)).throttle(
    reachRps(15) in (1 seconds),
    holdFor(10 minute))
```

I'm assuming here that I will have 45 available users (`constantConcurrentUsers(45)`) to perform the 15 requests per second (`reachRps(15)`), I will reach this speed in 1 second (`in (1 seconds)`) an I will hold this speed for 10 minutes (`holdFor(10 minutes)`)

I've tried with 15 constantConcurrentUsers users instead of 45 and the same results.

**The question is:**
Why the max amount of concurrent requests that I can see in the results is 13 and why actually the mean amount of requests per second is more or less 5?

[image]

How could I achieve the described scenario?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/#throttling):

> You still have to inject users at the scenario level. Throttling tries
>   to ensure a targeted throughput with the given scenarios and their
>   injection profiles (number of users and duration). It’s a bottleneck,
>   ie an upper limit. If you don’t provide enough users, you won’t reach
>   the throttle. If your injection lasts less than the throttle, your
>   simulation will simply stop when all the users are done. If your
>   injection lasts longer than the throttle, the simulation will stop at
>   the end of the throttle.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean because I'm actually injecting the users in scn.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(45). Again, I've tried with 15 and 45...

Comment: throttle sets an UPPER limit. It's your job to produce enough load to reach this limit. And if you feel like you can't reach it while you should, it probably means you're hitting another limit: poor CPU or bandwidth specs on the injector machine, antivirus, system under test not being able to cope with the load, anti-DDos protections...